# Query firestore database for document id

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query a firestore database for document id. Currently I have the following code:

```
db.collection('books').where('id', '==', 'fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5').get()
```

I don't get a result. But when I query for a different field it works:

```
db.collection('books').where('genre', '==', 'biography').get()
```

How is the name of the document id called?

Comment: Try: `const docRef = doc(db, collection_name, doc_id);` and then `wanted_doc = await getDoc(docRef); `

Comment: how to get document id?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.collection('books').doc('fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5').get()
```

(The first query is looking for an explicit user-set field called 'id', which probably isn't what you want.)

Comment: Hey do you know how to get document ID that  obeys some condition mentioned in a query in firestore

Comment: What to do if we need multiple where case (multiple id)?

Comment: In python I get `AttributeError: 'CollectionReference' object has no attribute 'doc'`. Turns out the syntax there is `db.collection('books').document('longid').get()`

Comment: @Midhilaj : could it be that document id's are unique?

Comment: @Midhilaj in my case i have another collection where i have document of each user which store the data that satisfy a specific condition. i have very limited conditions e.g what book is uploaded by which user.

Answer (score 333):

I am a bit late, but there is actually a way to do this

```
db.collection('books').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', 'fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5').get()
```

This might be useful when you're dealing with firebase security rules and only want to query for the records you're allowed to access.

Comment: Can you state what is firebase.firestore.FieldPath is initialized from?

Comment: It is defined in the firebase package, you don't need to initialize it.

Comment: If anyone else is struggling to find this import its "import { firestore } from 'firebase';"

Comment: For node.js the import appears to be: const firebase = require("firebase"); I abandoned using documentId for now, so cannot say if it will work well together with require("@google-cloud/firestore"); – nsandersen 47 mins ago   Edit    Delete

Comment: Perfect. I used it for `.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", listOfReferences)`.

Comment: Just want to add: You legit get document delete snapshot notifications from this vs nothing on the `.doc` interface

Comment: This is awesome. Where did you see this?

Comment: **Android:** `List<String> lst;`, `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("collection_name").whereIn(FieldPath.documentId(), lst).get().addOnCompleteListener(...);`

Comment: how to do this in cloud function

Comment: In Flutter: firestore.collection("collection_name").where(FieldPath.documentId, whereIn: mList).getDocuments();

Comment: It's indeed useful when you're dealing with firebase security rules. You saved my day. Thank you very much.

Comment: if you use "where" condition the auto update will stop working????

Comment: in cloud function with nodejs this worked: import FieldPath = firestore.FieldPath; FieldPath.documentId()

Comment: To get access to `FieldPath`, you can :
`import { FieldPath } from "@google-cloud/firestore";`

And directly use `FieldPath.documentId()`

Answer (score 73):

You can use the `__name__` key word to use your document ID in a query.

Instead of this `db.collection('books').doc('fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5').get()` you can write

`db.collection('books').where('__name__', '==' ,'fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5').get()`.

In this case you should get an array of length `1` back.

The firebase docs mention this feature in the rules documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource

Comment: This is handy when using the Firestore UI in prod or in the emulator, where you can't use something like `db.collection('foo').doc('xxxx')`

Comment: This is what I needed on my cloud function implementation, client sends the doc ids and I need to query all docs with "in" and get docs

Comment: Thanks mate, that´s the information I was looking for!

Comment: @DivyanshuNegi The admin SDK has a `getAll()` function https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#getAll I think this what you are looking for. Right?

Comment: @JohnGordon Unfortunately the Firebase Web UI doesn't let me create a query with `__name__`. The apply button is just greyed out :(

Comment: Thanks for the example, I would have never realized it could be used that way from the documentation, tried it with the php sdk and it works.

Answer (score 51):

**June, 2021**

The new [v9 modular sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more?authuser=1#modular-version) is tree-shakeable and results in smaller compiled apps. It is recommended for all new Firestore apps.

```js
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const snap = await getDoc(doc(db, 'books', 'fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5'))

if (snap.exists()) {
  console.log(snap.data())
}
else {
  console.log("No such document")
}
```

This is based on the example from the [firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?authuser=1#get_a_document)

```js
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, "cities", "SF");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

if (docSnap.exists()) {
  console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
}
else {
  // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
  console.log("No such document!");
}
```

You could make this into a helper function

```js
async function getDocument (coll, id) {
  const snap = await getDoc(doc(db, coll, id))
  if (snap.exists())
    return snap.data()
  else
    return Promise.reject(Error(`No such document: ${coll}.${id}`))
}

getDocument("books", "fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5")
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer deserves to be much higher.

Comment: what is the variable db ?

Comment: `db` is a reference to your firestore database. You can see how to initialize firestore in the [Getting Started docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=1)

Answer (score 37):

While everyone is telling to use `.get()`, which is totally reasonable but it's not always the case.

Maybe you want to filter data based on `id` (using a `where` query for example).

This is how you do it in Firebase v9 modular SDK:

```js
import {collection, documentId} from 'firebase/firestore'

const booksRef = collection('books')

const q = query(booksRef, where(documentId(), '==', 'fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5'))
```

Comment: thanks! this is the right answer for *both* the query AND doc API's 

Answer (score 15):

You can get a document by its `id` following this pattern:

```js
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("Your collection")
  .doc("documentId")
  .get()
  .then((docRef) => { console.log(docRef.data()) })
  .catch((error) => { })
```

Answer (score 11):

Currently only working way for Cloud Functions if you really need to use this way:

```
// Import firebase-admin
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

// Use FieldPath.documentId()
admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()

 const targetUser = await db.collection("users").where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId() "==", "givenId").get();
```

Simpler way of this is directly using ID value thru path as there is only one document with given document ID:

```
const targetUser = await db.doc("users/"+ "givenId").get();
```

However, you may really need to use it if you are matching given IDs array to the Firebase collection like this:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const arr = ["id1", "id2"];
const refArr = arr.map(id => admin.firestore().collection("media").doc(id));

const m = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("media")
      .where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", refArr)
      .get();
```

This last example is from [this discussion](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/990#issuecomment-735246776)

Answer (score 2):

From [Firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) for Get a document.

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for more dynamic queries with a helper function, you can simply try this.

```
import { db} from '@lib/firebase';

import {query, collection, getDocs ,documentId } from "firebase/firestore";

const getResult = async (_value) => {
     const _docId = documentId()
     const _query = [{
        field: _docID,
        operator: '==',
        value: _value
      }]
// calling function
    const result = await getDocumentsByQuery("collectionName", qColl)
    console.log("job result: ", result) 
}

// can accept multiple query args
const getDocumentsByQuery = async (collectionName, queries) => {
    const queryArgs = [];
    queries.forEach(q => {
        queryArgs.push(
            where(q.field, q.operator, q.value)
        );
    });

    const _query = query(collection(db, collectionName), ...queryArgs);
    const querySn = await getDocs(_query);
   
   const documents = [];
    querySn.forEach(doc => {
        documents.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
    });

    return documents[0];
};
```

Comment: This piece helped me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the first link that came up when I was looking to solve it in the Golang SDK, so I'll add my solution in case anyone else is looking for it:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "cloud.google.com/go/firestore"
    firebase "firebase.google.com/go/v4"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

type (
    Car struct {
        ID    string
        Name  string  `firestore:"name"`
        Make  string  `firestore:"make"`
        Price float64 `firestore:"make"`
    }
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    // Use a service account
    options := option.WithCredentialsFile("PATH/TO/SERVICE/FILE.json")

    // Set project id
    conf := &firebase.Config{ProjectID: "PROJECT_NAME"}

    // Initialize app
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, conf, options)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Get firestore client
    client, err := app.Firestore(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    collectionRef := client.Collection("CAR_COLLECTION")

    // firestore.DocumentID == "__name__" 
    docSnap, err := collectionRef.Where(firestore.DocumentID, "==", collectionRef.Doc("001")).Get(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Unmarshall item
    car := Car{}
    docSnap.DataTo(&car)
    car.ID = docSnap.Ref.ID

    // Print car list
    fmt.Println(car)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just to clear confusion here**

Remember, You should use `async/await` to fetch data whether fetching full `collection` or a single `doc`.

```js
async function someFunction(){
 await db.collection('books').doc('fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5').get();
}
```