# Can I listen to a single document in Firestore with a StreamBuilder?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to listen to changes in a single document of a collection, but I can't get it to work.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection("events").document(widget.documentID).get().asStream(),
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm using the **.asStream()** method, but I'm only getting the document once. If I change the data in the Firebase console, nothing updates unless I reopen the view.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason you are only getting the document once is because the [`DocumentReference.get`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/get.html) method originally only returns a `Future` and using `asStream` will only return that ***one*** single `Future` to the `Stream`.

The `cloud_firestore` package, however, has a built-in method of listening to documents properly.
You can use [`DocumentReference.snapshots`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/snapshots.html) instead, which returns a `Stream` of every change of that document.

In your code, you will only have to replace `.get().asStream()` by `.snapshots()`.

Comment: Great answer. I didn't even know `DocumentReference.snapshots()` existed, and it's great for this use-case. On other platforms you'll have to do a query on `FieldPath.documentId` as shown in Denys' answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52252264

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get a single document use Future builder instead of Stream Builder.

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                                              future: Firestore.instance
                                                  .collection('users')
                                                  .document(widget.puid)
                                                  .get(),
                                              builder: (context,
                                                  AsyncSnapshot<
                                                          DocumentSnapshot>
                                                      snapshot) {
                                                if (snapshot.hasError)
                                                  return Center(
                                                    child: Text(snapshot
                                                        .hasError
                                                        .toString()),
                                                  );
                                                return snapshot.hasData
                                                    ? Text(
                                                        "${snapshot.data['username']}",
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            color:
                                                                kPrimaryColor,
                                                            fontSize: 18,
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight
                                                                    .bold),
                                                      )
                                                    : Container();
                                              },
                                            ),
```