# How to set up a realtime listener for document title within firebase collection - python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to listen to a firebase collection for a document creation.

The firebase documentation lays it out like this:

```py
# Create a callback on_snapshot function to capture changes
def on_snapshot(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    print(u'Callback received query snapshot.')
    print(u'Current cities in California:')
    for doc in col_snapshot:
        print(u'{}'.format(doc.id))

col_query = db.collection(u'cities').where(u'state', u'==', u'CA')

# Watch the collection query
query_watch = col_query.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
```

Instead of u'state' inside of the where(), is there some way to reference the document title? (The title is not present within the document)

I've tried using `u'__name__'` but get the error:

`RuntimeError: Error 3:  a filter on __name__ must be a document resource name`

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript SDK seems to have an explicit options for it as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52252264):

> ```
> db.collection('books').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', 'fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5').get()
> ```

So `firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()` indicates the document ID.

There is no direct equivalent in Python, but you can accomplish the same by querying on `__name__`, which is the internal name of that field:

```
col_query = db.collection(u'cities').where(u'__name__', u'==', u'your_document_id')
```

Comment: Querying on `__name__` returns the following error: `RuntimeError: Error 3:  a filter on __name__ must be a document resource name`

Comment: I can think of a few work arounds, but this seems like it should be possible