# Firestore Perform an additional 'where' on an existing document

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, thonny

Is it possible to perform an additional 'where' when fetching a specific document?

Fetching a document based on an available key works perfectly:

```
db = firestore.client()
dockey = 'mykey'
doc_ref = db.collection(u'mydocuments').document(u'%s' % (dockey))
doc = doc_ref.get()
```

But I want to limit my reads, so I only want the document that correspond to an additional 'where' statement. I would expect something like this:

```
doc = doc_ref.where(u'field',u'==',u'one').get()
```

But unfortunately nothing seems to work.... Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a composite query? eg.

```py
doc_ref = (db.collection(u'mydocuments')
           .where(FieldPath.document_id(), u'==', dockey)
           .where(u'field', u'==', u'one'))
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it, but doesn't seem to work.
Here someone suggests using '__name__'  because there seems to be no direct equivalent in Python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56676006/how-to-set-up-a-realtime-listener-for-document-title-within-firebase-collection
Tried it too, be also without luck.. so I'm kinda stuck with this. unless someone else has another solution.