# Query collection by document id

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking for a way to query by the document id instead of a field.

It might look something like that:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('tournaments').where(documentId, searchInput)
```

In this case `searchInput` is an incomplete documentId.

I saw a solution on Stackoverflow, but it isn't for flutter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52252264/8539070

Another thing to keep in mind is that I am trying to display a list of all documents in a collection that match some part of the id.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to have more than one document with the same document id in Cloud Firestore, which is why a query for your document id is most likely not the solution you are looking for.

You can simply fetch a single document using the [`document` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/document.html). This returns a [`DocumentReference`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html), which also allows you to [`get` the document](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/get.html) and listen to [`snapshots`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/snapshots.html).

```dart
Firestore.instance.collection('tournaments').document(documentId).snapshots()
```

Comment: Sorry about my bad wording, I am trying to implement a search function and need to get all documents in a collection that have an id which includes the search string.

Comment: @jonasxd360 That is not possible if you are looking for word search. You can only use `isGreaterThanOrEqual` and `isLessThanOrEqual`. Otherwise, take a look at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search).

Comment: What if I perform the search locally? Could I download all documents and then search through their id's locally?

Comment: @jonasxd360 Sure. It would be something along the lines of `documents.where((documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot.documentID.contains(searchString)).toList()` to get a list of all documents that contain the search string in their document id.

Answer (score 17):

You can also get several documents by their id using:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('tournaments')..where(FieldPath.documentId, whereIn: myIdList).snapshots()
```

where myIdList is a List

Enjoy

Comment: Is there a limit on number of items in the myIdList?

Comment: FieldPath.documentId - saved my day!