# Is there any way I can query Firestore query condition based on fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase in my React Native app. I have a collection of users and in that, I have documents and the ids of the documents are custom (using users' phone numbers as ids) and in that, I have blocked users array field in which I will add the users who are blocked by the user. I want to show the list where user can only see the users who are not blocked.

I am getting all the users list and I want to filter them and fetch only the people not blocked by the user.

```js
var getUsersList = async() => {
  const findUser = await firestore().collection('users').get();
  if (findUser.docs[0] != undefined && findUser.docs[0]._exists){
    setUserList(findUser.docs)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey there. Can you provide an example for this line?: "I want to show the list where user can only see the users who are not blocked." I am finding it hard to understand. Does the list of block users contain numbers? or is it an array of subcollection of users?.

Comment: the app is like social media like we have in facebook user can block any other user so on the main page I am showing the users friends cards and have block friend option when a user block any of his friend then that friend will not seen in those list

Comment: The code you have added seems as you mentioned, getting all the users but what you have tried to filter them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that your firestore collection is similar to this one:

[image]

If that is the case, then I have structured your requirement in the three functions below:

1.`readBlockedNumbers` to return the array of blocked numbers that the user has.
2.`show_nonBlockedUsers`that receives the array of the blocked numbers from the previous method and displays the users who are not in this array.
3. `test` to coordinate the execution of the above two methods.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('/home/keys.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const db = admin.firestore();

async function readBlockedNumbers(docId){
  const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(docId);
  const doc = await userRef.get();
  if (!doc.exists) {
    console.log('No such document!');
    return [];
  } 
  else 
  {
    return doc.data()['blocked_numbers'];
  }

async function show_nonBlockedUsers(blocked_users){
  console.log('Array length:', blocked_users.length);
  
  if(blocked_users.length == 0)
  return;
  
  const userRef = db.collection('users');
  const snapshot = await userRef
    .where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'not-in', blocked_users)
    .get();
  
  if (snapshot.empty) {
    console.log('No matching documents.');
    return;
  }  
  
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
  });
}

async function test(){
  const docId = '202-555-0146';
  //'202-555-0102'
  const blocked_users = await readBlockedNumbers(docId);
  await show_nonBlockedUsers(blocked_users);
}
```

Important here is how to use the `not-in` operator and the method admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId().
I have found the `not-in` operator [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not-in) and the method `firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()` referenced in this other [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47876754/query-firestore-database-for-document-id) since the `id` cannot be passed like the other document fields in the where clause.

Please refer to the firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not-in) as well for the limitations of the `not-in` operator.

I hope you find this useful.