# How to filter out certain documents in a firestore query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking to implement a friends search function in my social app. For this I try to query for every user's document in the `users` collection of the DB, but it should exclude some specific documents like users who the current user is already friends with or request pending.

Is it possible to query for all the users documents, excluding specific documents by passing those documents reference ID's in Firestore.

If not, can somebody say a way to structure the data so that I can implement this functionality. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `not-in` query. Here would be a simple example (taken from the docs):

```js
citiesRef.where('country', 'not-in', ['USA', 'Japan']);
```

Since you want to query by the ID, you can use `firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()` as the field name ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52252264/9150652))

```js
citiesRef.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'not-in', ['123', '456']);
```

Alternatively you might try to use the `'__name__'` field-name ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62150539/9150652)):

```js
citiesRef.where('__name__', 'not-in', ['123', '456']);
```

- Docs for `not-in`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any
- Docs for `documentId`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#static-documentid

Comment: Thanks, with array not-in documentation says that for single query you can only compare 10 values, so if it more than 10 is there is any way other than use multiple queries.

Comment: @NawazMohamed Can't think of one, but you could certainly automate the creation of that compound query, so the downsides aren't that big.

Comment: Hi, is it not possible to use fieldPath with orderBy, it returns error `'FirestoreFieldPath' cannot be used in conjunction with a different Query.orderBy() parameter`

Comment: @NawazMohamed seems so - maybe open another question for that, as it is not included in your original question.