# querying for document id with firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, get, uuid

I have the database design below.

[image]

I was wondering how I would be able to use an id like `KeXrsroFOeMs4XNjgC7h`to retrieve the value for that document. Here is my current code:

```
db.collection('users',).where(id, '==', id)
    .get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
        // Contents of first document
        resolve(querySnapshot.docs[0].data());
      } else {
        resolve("No such document!");
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting document: ", error);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to fetch a single document by ID then use `get()` on a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) instead. You don't need a query for that:

```
db.collection('users').doc(id).get().then((snap) => {
  if (snap.exists) {
    const data = snap.data();
    console.log(data);
  } else {
    console.log("Document does not exist");
  }
})
```

Comment: If you really want to use a query though, you can use `FieldPath.documentId()` for the field. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/47876754, which is also a top result when I [search for the topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=querying+for+document+id+with+firestore).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Tried this FieldPath.documentId() solution in several ways after going through several solutions. But it just doesn't work in nodejs with firebase-admin pkg. I am using the latest version as of now, 11.11.0 but it still doesn't support FieldPath

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong here: `db.collection('users',).where(id, '==', id)`. Why the "," here `('users',)`? And you don't need to use `.where()` to achieve what you want.

Here's how to do it in a try/catch block; *make sure `id` is defined*

```
  try {
   const docRef = db.collection('users').doc(id);
   const doc = await docRef.get();
   if (doc.exists) {
    // Document data
    console.log(doc.data());
    } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
   }
  } catch (error) {
   console.log("Error getting document: ", error);
 }
```