# How to search document by custom id in firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I load data from a file

```
{
    id: '1081',
    title: "Some Prod",
    type: "tap",
    description: "Some Prod",    
    imageUrl: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/.../tooal.jpg',         
    price: 5.99,
    quantity: "1 unit",
    size: "XL",
    rating: 4 
  }
```

and the code used is

```
  return Promise.all(items.map(item => {
      const { id, ...data } = item;
      return db.collection(collectionName)
        .doc(id)
        .set(data);
  }));
```

Now the search function, gives no results

```
  const {id} = data;
  const store = admin.firestore();

  const querySnapshot = await store.collection("products")
      .doc(id)
      .get();

  const product = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
    ...doc.data(),
    id: doc.id,
  }));
```

Search from firestore is also not giving the results (0 records found for search)
The only types available are Number, String, Boolean, so used string (assuming String can be ' ' or " )

[image]

How to make my search work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not at all performing the query that you want.  This code is accessing a *single document* using its Firestore document ID, not the `id` field in the document:

```
  const querySnapshot = await store.collection("products")
      .doc(id)
      .get();
```

(Also, that code does not return a QuerySnapshot object. It returns a DocumentSnapshot, because there can be only one document in a collection with a particular ID.)

If you want to filter documents on a field (any field, even if it's called `id`), you need to follow the instructions in the [documentation for query filters](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#simple_queries) for that:

```
  const querySnapshot = await store.collection("products")
      .where("id", "==", id)
      .get();
```

If you look at your screenshot of the console in your question, you will see that it's actually recommending this to you.

Comment: I did try that model before. but chnaged based on 
 - (The first query is looking for an explicit user-set field called 'id', which probably isn't what you want.) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47876754/query-firestore-database-for-document-id

Comment: It's up to you to determine if you want to use a field or the document ID.  But as I explained, they are not the same query, nor the same code.

Comment: I understood your point document snapshot.   const productDoc = await store.collection("products").doc(idString).get();   and return productDoc.data(). What should I do to run the OOTB firebase query as in screenshot

Comment: That's what I show in my answer. There is even a link to the documentation.

Comment: sure. I accepted the answer. my question was how to search in cloud firestore using filter? note: I want to search only on id.