# Python Cloud Function - How to Query Firestore with documentID? (where)

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am attempting to filter my data based on the `documentId`. My objective is to retrieve a random document. Unfortunately, I am unable to find a way to achieve this within a Python cloud function.

My current code looks like this:

```py
result = firestore_client.collection("Quotes").where(filter=fs.FieldFilter(**'__name__'** , '>=', random_character)).limit(1).get()
```

In other languages it seems to work, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52252264/11030722:

```
db.collection('books').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', 'fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5').get()
```

P.S.: It also doesn't work for me without using `FieldFilter`. Thanks for any assistance.

I've tried `'__name__'` and `firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()`, but both did not work.

Comment: And you're not able to just get() the document directly using a document reference built with the ID, like `client.collection(...).document(...).get()` as you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)?  That's essentially the same thing.  Using a where filter doesn't have any advantage with what you're showing here.

Comment: No i didn't tried this. could you provide a short example, on how i could do this? Thanks for fast response :)

Comment: Use the link to the documentation that I provided.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't read it correctly. I believe this approach may not work in my case because I don't know the documentId. For example, I want to retrieve all documents whose documentId starts with 'x'.

Comment: If you don't know the ID, then using a where filter with equality won't do any better - your result set will contain 0 documents. Selecting a random document is actually very difficult to do well.  You should [read this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection) thoroughly to understand the issues involved that apply to all Firestore clients all of the time.

Comment: Yeah. i am exectly trying this. From this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54801398/11030722
i am trying to achive this: quotes.where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '>=', key).limit(1).get()
That is my goal but it seems impossible in python.

Comment: If it ends up being impossible, you could also just put the document ID into a normal field and use that instead.

Comment: Yes, but in order to implement that, I would have to refactor a significant portion of my application. It seems like the wrong approach, especially considering that it is possible with other languages.